# Change rectangle color in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent

How to change the color of rectangle ? I want change it to yellow color. I added  `g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);` inside `rectDraw`, but the color of the rectangle still remain the same. Can someone tell me what wrong I did please?

```
 public class SelectSeat {

    static JFrame frame;

    public JPanel createContentPane() throws IOException
    {

        JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();
        RectDraw rect= new RectDraw();
        rect.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(330,35)); //for size
        totalGUI.setLayout(null);
        totalGUI.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        totalGUI.add(rect);
        Dimension d = rect.getPreferredSize();
        rect.setBounds(100, 20, d.width, d.height); // for location
        return totalGUI;
    }

        void setVisible(boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    static void createAndShowGUI() throws IOException
    {

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        frame = new JFrame("Seat Selection");
        //Create and set up the content pane.
        SelectSeat demo = new SelectSeat();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(535, 520);
        frame.setLocation(500,220);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class RectDraw extends JPanel
    {
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);  
             g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
             g.drawString("Movie Sceen", 130, 20);   
            }


    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: `I added g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);` I don't see that call in the posted code. Do you fill a Rectangle after making the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to change the color of rectangle ? I want change it to yellow color.

You need to set the color to yellow, followed by filling a rectangle the size of the component.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);  
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawString("Movie Sceen", 130, 20);   
}
```

And for what its worth:

```
totalGUI.setLayout(null);
```

I would recommend against using null Layouts. Use a [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) appropriate to the task, and remember that you can nest layouts within the Component hierarchy.

Comment: Use LayoutManager instead of null layouts ?

Comment: Yes. See [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122338/swing-gridbaglayout-component-resizing/17122843#17122843) for a description why you want to stay away from null layouts